# Flutter - Making several calls to an API and updating the UI with the changes gotten back from internet

Tags: android, api, flutter, dart

`

```
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'dart:convert';

class BinDetails {
  BinDetails({this.url});
  String url;
  Future getCardMetadata() async {
    try {
      http.Response response = await http.get(url);
      if (response.statusCode == 200) {
        String data = response.body;
        print(jsonDecode(data));
        return jsonDecode(data);
      } else {
        print(response.statusCode);
        print(response.body);
      }
    } catch (e) {
      print("An error occurred: $e");
    }
  }

  
}`

`
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
    import 'package:extension/extension.dart';
    import 'package:mask_text_input_formatter/mask_text_input_formatter.dart';
    import 'package:binlist/services/networking.dart';
    
    String url = "https://lookup.binlist.net/$cardNumber";
    String cardNumber = "";
    String cardScheme = "-";
    String cardType = "-";
    String cardLength = "-";
    String prepaid = "-";
    String bankName = "-";
    String countryName = "-";
    
    class CardDetails extends StatefulWidget {
      @override
      _CardDetailsState createState() => _CardDetailsState();
    }
    
    class _CardDetailsState extends State<CardDetails> {
      Future<dynamic> getCalledCardMetaData() async {
        BinDetails getBinDetails = BinDetails(url: url);
        var cardMetaData = await getBinDetails.getCardMetadata();
    
        if (cardMetaData['scheme'] == null) {
          setState(() {
            cardScheme = "-";
          });
        }
        if (cardMetaData['type'] == null) {
          setState(() {
            cardType = "-";
          });
        }
    
        if (cardMetaData['number']['length'] == null) {
          setState(() {
            cardLength = "-";
          });
        }
        if (cardMetaData['prepaid'] == null) {
          setState(() {
            prepaid = "-";
          });
        }
        if (cardMetaData['bank'] == null) {
          setState(() {
            bankName = "-";
          });
        }
        if (cardMetaData['country'] == null) {
          setState(() {
            countryName = "-";
          });
        }
        setState(() {
          cardScheme = cardMetaData['scheme'];
          cardType = cardMetaData['type'];
          cardLength = cardMetaData['number']['length'].toString();
          if (cardLength == "null") {
            cardLength = "-";
          }
          prepaid = cardMetaData['prepaid'].toString();
          if (prepaid == "false") {
            prepaid = "No";
          } else if (prepaid == "true") {
            prepaid = "Yes";
          } else if (prepaid == "null") {
            prepaid = "-";
          }
          bankName = cardMetaData['bank']['name'];
          countryName = cardMetaData['country']['name'];
          print(cardScheme);
          print(countryName);
          print(cardLength);
          print(cardType);
          print(bankName);
          print(prepaid);
        });
        return cardMetaData;
      }
    
      final _imputedNumber = TextEditingController();
    
      void clearCardNumber() {
        setState(() {
          _imputedNumber.clear();
          cardScheme = "-";
          cardType = "-";
          cardLength = "-";
          prepaid = "-";
          bankName = "-";
          countryName = "-";
          print(cardNumber);
        });
      }
    
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        var maskFormatter = MaskTextInputFormatter(
            mask: '#### ####', filter: {"#": RegExp(r'[0-9]')});
        return Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(
            title: Text(
              'Bin List',
            ),
          ),
          body: Column(
            children: [
              Expanded(
                child: Column(
                  children: [
                    Container(
                      width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.9,
                      child: TextField(
                        inputFormatters: [maskFormatter],
                        controller: _imputedNumber,
                        onChanged: (value) {
                          String maskedNumber = value;
                          cardNumber =
                              maskedNumber.replaceAll(new RegExp(r'\s'), '');
                          print(cardNumber);
                          print(cardNumber.length);
                         
                          if (cardNumber.length == 8) {
                            getCalledCardMetaData();
                          }
                        },
                        keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                        textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                        decoration: InputDecoration(
                          contentPadding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 5.0),
                          enabledBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
                            borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.black54),
                          ),
                          focusedBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
                            borderSide:
                                BorderSide(color: Colors.lightBlue, width: 2.0),
                          ),
                          suffix: TextButton(
                            onPressed: clearCardNumber,
                            child: Icon(
                              Icons.clear,
                              color: Colors.grey.shade600,
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),`
```

I made an app that uses the bin list API (https://lookup.binlist.net/YOUR_CARD_NUMBER_HERE) to get the metadata of the card. When I start the app from cold, type the card number for CARD A, and make the get request, I get the card metadata back and which is used to update the UI. When I clear the numbers for CARD A and type in the card NUMBER for CARD B, I still get the metadata for CARD A instead of CARD B. But when I start the app from cold again, and type in the card number for CARD B then and only then do i get the correct metadata for CARD B being updated on the UI.

I have tried to debug this by printing the card numbers to the console whenever the values for the TextField changes. I get the right numbers being typed and this typed numbers are what is being sent to the API but the metadata for the second card is not being retrieved from the API. I have to start the app from cold every time to retrieve the right metadata. What can I do to resolve this? Thanks.

[[image: Screenshots of CARD A and CARD B][1]]

Answer (score 1):

In your code after evaluating all conditions, try calling your function that clears your previous values before calling getCalledCardMetaData().

```
if (cardNumber.length == 8) {
    clearCardNumber();
    getCalledCardMetaData();
}
```

Comment: This doesn't solve it. It clears the card numbers before the call to the API which the cancel icon does too when I tap on it